# Simple XML Call to a member function addChild() on boolean

Tags: php, simplexml, sitemap

I have a problem composing XML sitemap using **simple xml PHP function**, having *almost equal situation* and when `sitemap` tag, it is not working:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>');

$sitemap = $xml->addChild("sitemap");
$sitemap->addChild("loc", "http://www.example.com/sitemap-1.xml");
```

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function addChild() on boolean

[image]

This is **working** **reliably**:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>');

$url = $xml->addChild("url");
$url->addChild("loc", "http://www.example.com/sitemap-2.xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by simple mistake.

(you have - maybe forgot to change - closing tag from urlset to **sitemapindex**):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></urlset>');
```

Correct:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"></sitemapindex>');
```

Comment: @frankie You should scroll the code to the right, as it's in the most end of the line.